# How can I change undo behavior in Vim?

Tags: vim-windows, undo-redo

I'm new to Vim and install that in windows 10.

I write this instructions in Vim then in normal mode pressed `u` and all the instructions disappeared.

```js
console.log(899) hello you can write some simple Javascript instructions here....
```

But when I use VsCode and press <kbd>Ctrl-z</kbd> all the instructions will not disappear. VsCode deletes word by word where Vim deletes all the things.

How can I set this behavior in Vim?

Comment: `u` is to undo the last action in a whole. Here, the action was to put a full line (not a word.) The undo will work as you expect if you insert one word a time… However, you can delete a word the cursor is on with `diw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undo action is per-line if you write a bunch of lines in insert-mode.
This is natural as most languages use 1 statement per line (usally).

To override this behavior while in insert mode use `Ctrl-g u` to manually add an undo point.

Comment: Actually, if you type `i<multiple lines of text><esc>`, then `u` removes all text, since the action was a single insert.

Comment: I don't get that behavior if there are line-breaks in the insert action. I can see each line in my undoTree.

Comment: You might have a mapping on `<enter>` in insert-mode; try `vim --clean`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You are right.  `vim --clean` gives the behavior as you said. Must be something in my config/plugin that changed that behavior.

Comment: Thanks, It works for me.

Comment: Also these below commands are helpfull for me: `set backspace= indent,eol,start   nnoremap <BS> X `

Answer (score 1):

One way to get a behavior to want you want is to have the following mapping:

```
inoremap <space> <C-g>u<space>
```

It create a new undo operation each time you insert a space.

Comment: can I have both of this behaviors in vim? default behavior and your solution together?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean but I suppose the answer is no :-) If you mean to have to kinds of undo one with the standard behavior and one with the 'word' undo behavior I suppose it is not possible since the there is only one undo stack and I don't see ways to make the distinction between the kind of undo state.

Comment: You understood what I mean.